# Simple C program with nested for loops stops working in windows powershell

Tags: c, loops, powershell, for-loop, nested

I successfully compiled a simple C code in powershell, the problem is whenever I input a number such that the conditions I've set for the for loops to be run is satisfied, the program stops working ( with the windows 10 dialog box appearing, notifying me that it is trying to find a solution to fix the problem and all)

Also, I compiled the code using the powershell(x86) console in windows 10, could that have caused the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x, y, j, i, foo;
    int count = 0, prim[1000];
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

for(y = 1; y < x; y++){
    for(j = 1; j <= y; j++){
        foo = j - 1;
        if (y % foo  == 0){
            count++;        
        }   
      }
    printf("%d", count);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need a `;` at the end of the line `int x, y, j, i, foo`, for one.

Comment: yes, just a typo. The problem still stands.

Comment: This program crashes when compiled with Visual Studio too, so I don't think powershell has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for(j = 1; j <= y; j++){  foo = j - 1; if (y % foo  == 0){`  ---> `y % 0` --> undefined behavior.

> The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the second; the result of the % operator is the remainder. In both operations, **if the value of the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined.** C11dr  §6.5.5  5

Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using #include < conio.h> and aslo getch(); after the last printf used. If this doesn't work there should be a problem with the compiler you are using.

Comment: Were you able to reproduce and test it?

Answer (score 0):

Your program fails because foo==0 in the first iteration of the inner loop.

Comment: Changing foo = j - 1 to foo = j have removed the error. Thank you. I thought that the value of j would have been updated to 2,  does this mean that the for loop will only do j++ once the loop has completed the first iteration?

Comment: @Jeff. Yes, loop counter is incremented at the end of an iteration. Pls, accept the answer if it helped.